# how to search between three different values in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have a MySql database with some data like this:

```
str = '554a41a6e4d9d  677  3'
```

and i want to search all the values that **exactly match the '677'**  part (the second part of text, after the first).

How i can accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

If the 'parts' are delimited by space, you can use `like`:

```
SELECT [cols] FROM [table] WHERE [col] LIKE '% 677 %'
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Fulltext` type for the `column`. And then use a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE MATCH (column) AGAINST ('677');
```